# TypeORM Query entity with jsonb column by json property

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity which holds a json object called "stats". Stats has multiple properties which Id like to order my findAll method by.

I tried everything but I can not get the query to work using my attempts.

This is how I am trying to find all Collection entities ordered by the stats.one_day_volume property

The error I am getting with my last approach shown below is
"missing FROM-clause entry for table "stats"

```js
    const result = await getRepository(Collection)
      .createQueryBuilder('collection')
      .orderBy('collection.stats.one_day_volume', "DESC")
      .take(take)
      .skip(skip)
      .getMany();
```

This is the entity class

```js
@Entity()
export class Collection {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({nullable:true})
  external_link: string;

  @Column({nullable:true})
  description: string;

  @Column()
  slug: string;

  @Column({nullable:true})
  image_url: string;

  @Column({nullable:true})
  banner_image_url: string;

  @Column()
  dev_seller_fee_basis_points: string;

  @Column()
  safelist_request_status: string;

  @Column({nullable:true})
  payout_address: string;

  @Column('jsonb')
  primary_asset_contracts: AssetContract[];

  @Column("simple-json")
  traits: object;

  @Column("jsonb", {array:true, nullable:true})
  payment_tokens: PaymentToken[];

  @Column("simple-array", {nullable:true})
  editors: string[];

  @Column("jsonb")
  stats: CollectionStats;

  @Column({ type: 'timestamptz' })
  created_date: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a way to `orderBy` on `jsonb` column

But there's an issue when you try to `getMany` with it.

So my workaround was to have it this way (use getRawMany instead of getMany):

```
const result = await getRepository(Collection)
  .createQueryBuilder('collection')
  .orderBy("collection.stats->>'one_day_volume'", "DESC")
  .take(take)
  .skip(skip)
  .getRawMany();
```

So apparently with `getRawMany` it's working well.

To get it as an entity you can try create it from repo like so:

```
    const repo = await getRepository(Collection);
    const resultAsEntities = repo.create(result);
```

But looks like there are sometimes this won't work as expected due to relations and other objects so you may try achieve it this way:

```
const resultIds = result.map(item => item.id);
const resultAsEntities = await getRepository(Collection).findByIds(resultIds);
```